# Filtering data with key value in the object inside an array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, filter

I have an array of SKUs of a product in MongoDB and I want to sort it as following. I tried it with Map and set but it is returning only unique values. I want this response from the API. How can I achieve this. I already did it for categories with recursive function parentId but this is tricky.

```
Product = {
         ...
         Skus[
            {
             skuId: "Boo"
              name: "Foo"
              color: "red"
              size: "small"
             },
             {
             skuId: "Moo"
              name: "Foo"
              color: "red"
              size: "large"
             },
             {
             skuId: "Roo"
              name: "Soo"
              color: "yellow"
              size: "small"
             },
             {
             skuId: "Yoo"
              name: "Hoo"
              color: "red"
              size: "medium"
             },
            
}
```

I want to arrange SKUs like this

```
Product = { ...
               Skus: [ 
                       {red: [small, medium, large]}]
```

I want to filter the products by the color of the SKUs as I want to create a filter.

Comment: isn't red should be like `{red: [small, medium, large]}]`?

Comment: Yes, it should have all the unique values for the size available.

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/noRCJ-rANLq) what do you want?

Comment: @J.F. Yes, This is what I want but how can we do this with mongoose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain the result using moongoose you can use the same query used [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/noRCJ-rANLq) with your model in the controller.

For example:

```
YourModel.aggregate([{
    "$unwind": "$Skus"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$Skus.color",
      "size": {
        "$addToSet": "$Skus.size"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$arrayToObject": [
          [
            {
              "k": "$_id",
              "v": "$size"
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }])
.then(result => {})
.catch(e => {})
```

Comment: Actually, the collection is a list of products and I am executing a query on it by product Id. so it is MyCollection.findById(req.params.id).aggregate(..) so it is not working.

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/47f6li-THAY) using `$match` what do you want? If it is not correct update your answer with an schema example please.

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. I filtered the product I wanted and then I applied this.